# Android: How to format getIntent().getIntExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to retrieve the image resource file in another class, the intent putExtra has been placed in the MainActivity but I'm not sure how to retrieve that in the other class? I've tried getIntent().getIntExtra("category", search_name); but I just get errors. The idea is that the user claiks on the photo of a recipe category and then in the other class I can match that resource image file to the category name and retrieve the corresponding recipes.

Also this gridview slows down the app, how would I wrap and call this in an Async?

**MainActivity**

```
GridView gv = findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gv.setAdapter(new SetImageAdapter(this));
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Category.class);
                intent.putExtra("Category", SetImageAdapter.categories[position]); // put image data in Intent
                startActivity(intent); // start Intent

            }
        });
```

**GridView Adapter**

```
package com.stu54259.plan2cook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class SetImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static Integer[] categories = {
            R.drawable.african, R.drawable.american,
            R.drawable.asian, R.drawable.comfort,
            R.drawable.desserts, R.drawable.greek,
            R.drawable.italian, R.drawable.vegetarian,
            R.drawable.mexican,

    };
    private Context Cont;
    public SetImageAdapter(Context c) {
        Cont = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return categories.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imgview = new ImageView(Cont);
        imgview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(370, 250));
        imgview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imgview.setPadding(10,10,10, 10);
        imgview.setImageResource(categories[position]);
        return imgview;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity :

```
GridView gv = findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gv.setAdapter(new SetImageAdapter(this));
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Category.class);
                intent.putExtra("CategoryPosition", position); // put image data in Intent
                startActivity(intent); // start Intent

            }
        });
```

In your Category activity :

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("CategoryPosition",0);
int selectedDrawable = SetImageAdapter.categories[position];
//Get name of the selected drawable : 
String search_name =  getResources().getResourceEntryName(selectedDrawable);
```

The possibility reason why the performance of your `GridView` is slow is the `drawable` resource size, make sure that all image used has a small resolution as well as smaller size.

Comment: Thanks Ive implemented that and was thinking something like this int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("CategoryPosition",0);
        int selectedDrawable = SetImageAdapter.categories[position];
        if (selectedDrawable == 0) {
            search_name = "african";
            Log.d("Category name", search_name);
        }
        else if (selectedDrawable == 1) {
            search_name = "american";
        }
        else if (selectedDrawable == 2) {
            search_name = "asian";
        } etc might work but it doesn't.. Converted images to webp doesn't help either.

Comment: @RevansArdenPlease explain more, what are you looking now to achieve ? You want to get the name of selected `drawable`, for example if the selected `drawable` is `R.drawable.african` you want the `search_name` to be **african** ?

Comment: So what I want to achieve is that I want to set the variable search_name to either african, asian, mexican etc depending on the position clicked on the gridview.

Comment: @RevansArden I've updated my answer, please check it out

Comment: That sort of works, only displays results of position 0  though.